# I need to be able to collapse an unordered list bootstrap 2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When in tablet or phone view I need to be able to collapse this unordered list. Does anybody know how to with BootStrap 2?

```
<div class="row left-sidebar-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="left">Item A</li>
    <li class="right">Item 1</li>
    <li class="left">Item B</li>
    <li class="right">Item 2</li>
    <li class="left">Item C</li>
    <li class="right">Item 3</li>
    <li class="left">Item D</li>
    <li class="right">Item 4</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

The actual page can be found [here](http://skeeterz71.com/auto/test-dropdown-list.html)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217524/css-first-child-pseudo-class-with-unordered-list-bootstrap

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270423/bootstrap-collapsing-nav-li-menu

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured it out.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".left-sidebar-list">
simple collapsible
</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse in">


<div class="row left-sidebar-list">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="left">Item A</li>
                        <li class="right">Item 1</li>
                        <li class="left">Item B</li>
                        <li class="right">Item 2</li>
                        <li class="left">Item C</li>
                        <li class="right">Item 3</li>
                        <li class="left">Item D</li>
                        <li class="right">Item 4</li>
                    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

If you want to see it in action.... http://skeeterz71.com/auto/bootstrap-collapse.html